# Replace random values in a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, replace

Please advise how can I replace half of values in a column to NA:

```
# Generate 500 values with a skewed distribution
x1 <- round(rbeta(500,0.5,3)*100,0)

# Assign variable to a data frame
df <- data.frame(x1)

# Replace 250 random values in a column 'x1' to NA
df[sample(x1,250)] <- NA

The following mistake is shown:
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, sample(x1, 250), value = NA) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns
```

I understand why the mistake is shown, but I would like to force the replacement. Please advise on how can I do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Gregory...check this out.  It will help you format your posts so they are easier to read. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like you need

```
df$x1[sample(nrow(df),250)] <- NA
```