# R: Randomly Replacing Elements of a Data Frame with 0

Tags: r, dataframe, random, integer, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
var_1 = var_2 = var_3 = var_4 = var_5 =  c("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10")

my_data = data.frame(var_1,var_2,var_3,var_4,var_5)

my_data = rbind(my_data, my_data[rep(1, 100), ])

rownames(my_data) = 1:nrow(my_data)
```

The data looks like this:

```
    head(my_data)

                 var_1                var_2                var_3                var_4                var_5
1 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
2 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
3 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
4 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
5 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
6 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

**My Question:** I would like to randomly replace elements in this data frame with 0 - for instance, the final result should look something like this (for brevity, I am only showing the first row):

```
# desired result

                 var_1                var_2                var_3                var_4                var_5
1 1,0,3,0,5,6,0,0,9,10 1,2,0,4,5,0,0,8,9,0 1,0,3,0,0,0,0,8,9,0 1,2,3,4,0,6,7,0,0,10 1,2,0,4,5,0,7,8,0,10
```

I tried to do this with the following line of code ([Replace random values in a column in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459514/replace-random-values-in-a-column-in-a-dataframe)) :

```
my_data$var_1[sample(nrow(my_data),as.integer(0.5*nrow(my_data)) , replace = TRUE)] <- 0
my_data$var_2[sample(nrow(my_data),as.integer(0.5*nrow(my_data)), replace = TRUE)] <- 0
my_data$var_3[sample(nrow(my_data),as.integer(0.5*nrow(my_data)), replace = TRUE)] <- 0
my_data$var_4[sample(nrow(my_data),as.integer(0.5*nrow(my_data)), replace = TRUE)] <- 0
my_data$var_5[sample(nrow(my_data),as.integer(0.5*nrow(my_data)), replace = TRUE)] <- 0
```

But this is replacing ALL the elements of a row with 0 (instead of just replacing some of the elements within a row):

```
head(my_data)
                 var_1                var_2                var_3                var_4                var_5
1 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                    0                    0                    0
2                    0                    0 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                    0
3                    0 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                    0 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
4                    0 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                    0 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
5 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
6 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                    0 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10                    0
```

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how to get the desired result?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that allows you to specify a vector of probabilities `pnul` of becoming `0` in every column separately using `Map`. `length` of splitted string is being multiplied by the elements of `pnul` to get number of `sample`s set to zero. You may also set `pnul` to a scalar for same probability in all columns.

```
pnul <- c(.0, .2, .5, .8, 1)

res <- Map(\(x, a) {
  S <- strsplit(x, ',')
  sapply(S, \(s) {
    s[sample(seq_along(s), length(s)*a)] <- '0'
    paste(s, collapse=',')
  })
}, my_data, pnul) |> as.data.frame()

head(res)
#                  var_1                var_2                var_3                var_4               var_5
# 1 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  1,2,0,4,0,0,7,8,0,0  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,9,0 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
# 2 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 1,0,3,0,5,0,0,0,9,10  0,0,0,0,0,0,7,8,0,0 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
# 3 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,0,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,0,0,0,0,6,7,0,9,10 0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,10 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
# 4 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,0,5,6,7,0,9,10 0,0,3,0,5,0,7,0,9,10  0,0,0,4,0,0,7,0,0,0 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
# 5 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 0,2,0,4,5,0,7,0,0,10  1,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
# 6 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 0,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,9,10  1,2,3,0,5,0,7,0,0,0  0,0,0,4,5,0,0,0,0,0 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be one way to get to your aim:

In you example each row of a column is regarded as a one element vector therefore when you replace it all 1:10 are replaced by 0.

To avoid that one possible way is to separate this vector in rows with `separate_row` from `tidyr` package and after doing our calculation, bring it back with `toString`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_data %>% 
  separate_rows(starts_with("var")) %>% 
  group_by(id_Group =cumsum(var_1==1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("var"), ~replace(., sample(row_number(),  
                                        size = ceiling(0.4 * n()), replace = TRUE), 0))) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("var"), ~toString(.))) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-id_Group)
```

```
  var_1                         var_2                         var_3     var_4 var_5
   <chr>                         <chr>                         <chr>     <chr> <chr>
 1 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 7, 0, 9, 10 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0  0, 0, 3,~ 1, 2~ 0, 0~
 2 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 9, 0  1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0  1, 2, 3,~ 1, 0~ 1, 0~
 3 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0  1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 10 1, 2, 0,~ 1, 2~ 1, 2~
 4 1, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 10 0, 0, 0,~ 0, 0~ 0, 0~
 5 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9, 10 1, 0, 3,~ 1, 2~ 1, 2~
 6 1, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9, 10 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0  1, 0, 3,~ 1, 2~ 1, 2~
 7 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 10 0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0  1, 2, 3,~ 1, 2~ 1, 0~
 8 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8, 0, 0  1, 0, 3,~ 1, 0~ 0, 2~
 9 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 10 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0  1, 2, 0,~ 0, 0~ 0, 0~
10 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0  1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 10 1, 0, 3,~ 1, 2~ 1, 2~
# ... with 91 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way.
Create a function to sample `n` elements from each vector element, defaulting to 1, and `lapply` the function to the vectors to be changed. In the posted example all column vectors will be changed.

```r
options(width=205)

var_1 = var_2 = var_3 = var_4 = var_5 =  c("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10")
my_data = data.frame(var_1,var_2,var_3,var_4,var_5)
my_data = rbind(my_data, my_data[rep(1, 100), ])
rownames(my_data) = 1:nrow(my_data)

my_data1 <- my_data

randReplace <- function(x, n = 1L, split = ",") {
  y <- strsplit(x, split = split)
  z <- lapply(y, function(.y) {
    i <- seq_along(.y)
    m <- min(n, length(.y))
    .y[sample(i, m)] <- 0
    .y
  })
  z <- lapply(z, paste, collapse = split)
  unlist(z)
}

my_data[] <- lapply(my_data, randReplace)
head(my_data)
#>                  var_1                var_2                var_3                var_4                var_5
#> 1 1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9,10 0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,9,10
#> 2 1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9,10 0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
#> 3 1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,9,10 0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9,10
#> 4 1,2,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,9,10 1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
#> 5 1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,10 1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,9,10 0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,9,10
#> 6 1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,9,10  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,9,10  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

my_data1[] <- lapply(my_data1, randReplace, n = 4)
head(my_data1)
#>                  var_1                var_2                var_3                var_4                var_5
#> 1  1,2,3,4,0,0,0,8,9,0  0,2,0,0,5,6,7,8,9,0 1,0,0,4,0,6,0,8,9,10 0,0,3,4,0,0,7,8,9,10  1,0,3,4,5,6,0,8,0,0
#> 2  1,0,3,4,5,6,0,8,0,0  1,0,3,0,0,6,7,8,9,0 0,2,3,4,5,0,0,8,0,10 1,0,0,4,5,0,7,8,0,10  0,0,3,4,0,6,7,8,9,0
#> 3  0,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,0,0 0,2,0,0,5,6,7,8,0,10  1,2,0,4,5,6,0,0,9,0 0,2,0,0,5,0,7,8,9,10  0,2,0,4,5,0,7,8,9,0
#> 4 1,2,3,0,0,6,0,8,0,10  1,0,3,4,5,0,7,8,0,0 1,2,0,0,5,0,7,0,9,10  1,0,3,0,5,6,0,8,9,0 0,2,0,4,0,6,0,8,9,10
#> 5  1,2,3,4,0,0,7,0,9,0 0,0,0,0,5,6,7,8,9,10 0,0,3,4,5,6,0,0,9,10 0,2,3,4,0,0,7,0,9,10 1,0,0,0,5,6,7,8,0,10
#> 6 1,2,0,4,0,0,0,8,9,10 0,2,3,0,0,0,7,8,9,10 0,2,0,4,0,6,7,8,0,10 1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,10  0,2,0,4,0,6,7,8,9,0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>